# When Adar Begins we increase our Joy-משנכנס אדר מרבים בשמחה

Tags: halacha, calendar, simchah-joy-happiness, adar

משנכנס אדר מרבים בשמחה- When Adar Begins we increase our Joy (I know it is not in Shulchan Aruch or the Rambam) What is the practical application of it?

Comment: It means to do this http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/797/759

Comment: @DoubleAA to say Purim Torah was the kavana of Chazal?

Comment: Pashoot! Do you doubt that Chazal knew about Mi Yodeya's Purim Torah policy??

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36140/759

Comment: Ein Simcha Ela Torah

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Chasam Sofer](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14663&pgnum=126) says that it has little or no practical application, and indeed he says that this is why Rambam and Shulchan Aruch don't cite it as practical halachah.

However, the Minchas Elazar ([Nimukei Orach Chaim 686:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4751&pgnum=292)) raises several objections against the Chasam Sofer's position. He writes (quoting his own statement in another of his sefarim):

> אבל משנכנס אדר מרבין בשמחה נקט סתם כי
>   מדה טובה מרובה, ובאיזה דבר שנוכל אז
>   להרבות בשמחה מצוה איכא, וכל אחד ישער
>   בלבבו ונפשו... מצוה בכל מה דאפשר
>   להרבות בלבו ובעניניו בשמחה של מצוה
>   ולקיים דברי חכמים
>
> "But it just says 'when Adar begins we
>   increase our joy' without further
>   specification, because the good aspect
>   is greater [than the "decrease in joy"
>   during Av, for which specific areas
>   are mentioned]. So whatever we can do
>   to increase in joy - there is a
>   mitzvah in doing so, and each person
>   has to evaluate this according to his
>   own heart and soul... It is a mitzvah,
>   insofar as possible, to increase the
>   mitzvah-related joy in his heart and
>   in his affairs, and to fulfill the
>   words of the Sages."

Comment: Thanx alex for the Source essentially if I like playing football then in Adar I have a Mitzvah to do so very intresting. I am guessing the Issue the Minchas Elazar has is the Yerushalmi about Laining Meggilah?

Comment: He does mention that Yerushalmi, yes. As for playing football - bear in mind that Minchas Elazar specifies שמחה של מצוה.

Answer (score 4):

(.בבלי תענית כט) is the source of this verse. One possible application is mentioned in Mishna Berura 686.8 that if a person has a court case it is best if he can push it off till Adar. By winning the court case it definately adds Simcha.

Comment: That is well known,How is that an Increase in Joy?

Answer (score 3):

One can most effectively increase joy in Adar by increasing the joy of others.  Hence the Mitzvah of giving money to the needy and giving gifts to members of your community, with preference for those individuals that you have trouble getting along with! Imagine the world we can live in, if our truest, highest joy comes from the radiant faces of those we bring joy to...

Comment: Martin, Welcome to Judaism.SE and thank you for your *enlightening* perspective. If you could edit in a source for those obligations' extending back to rosh chodesh it would greatly improve your answer. I look forward to seeing you around!

Comment: Martin, allow me to echo @DoubleAA's welcome. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1286), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. I look forward to seeing you around.

Answer (score 1):

If it is understood as an instruction I would **assume** one should be happier in Adar than one was in Sh'vat.

If, on the other hand, it is merely a **description** of the state of affairs in Adar than  perhaps it describes the fact that people are happier in Adar than they are in Sh'vat.

Comment: The gemarah in Tannis says Kshem Shnechnasim lav Mimatin Bsimcha ken Mishnichnas Adar Marbin and instructions for getting sad in Av there are many Halachos

Comment: Citing that gemara in your question would enhance the question a great deal.

Comment: @SimchasTorah, I second Isaac.

Answer (score 1):

Chabad.org suggests that we can increase our joy mentally. That is, during Adar we should do our best to take everything optimistically, feel happy, be happy with what we have and "not kvetch."

While we should be constantly doing this, Adar is a month when we should be trying especially hard to be happy in everything we do.

There are also likely practical ways which was perhaps the original intent of the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Revach.net](http://revach.net/halacha/tshuvos/Rambam-Shulchan-Aruch-What-Happened-To-Halachic-Happiness-In-Adar/4390) quotes the Nimukei Orach Chaim from Piskei Tshuvos 686 footnote 17, who learns that, as they put it:

> ...anything we can do to increase our happiness is a kiyum of the mitzva.
>
> Because this Mitzva has no concrete guidelines and depends on the nature of each individual, says the Nimukei Orach Chaim, the Rambam and Shulchan Aruch do not bring it.  They only bring Halachos with concrete manifestations, which include aveilus in Av, but not happiness in Adar.