# Practically increasing simcha in Adar

Tags: purim, simchah-joy-happiness, adar

Does anyone have personal/practical suggestions of how to increase one's simcha in Adar?

([related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5792/when-adar-begins-we-increase-our-joy))

Comment: Lots of Torah learning!

Comment: Ein Simcha Ela K'Simchas haTorah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: **Get ready for Purim, by learning about why Purim is a joyous day and start internalizing those happy lessons.**

I already wrote [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35180/time-parameters-of-mishenichnas-adar-marbin-bsimcha/35181#35181), about 2 reasons why we increase joy in Adar - as a preparation for Purim. To recap:

1. According to the Michtav M'Eliyahu (Vol. 2 pg 125)  the happiness we feel on Purim is a הכרת הטוב - recognizing the goodness - of the miracle of Purim, which is all about revenge. HaShem took revenge on Haman and ונהפוך הוא - turned the tables - and made Mordechai the Prime Minister in his stead.

   **The joy required to celebrate this הכרת הטוב efficiently requires work and preparation,** continues the Michtav M'Eliyahu, and one needs to start this preparation as soon as Adar starts, in order to be in the right mood when Purim arrives.
2. The Ramchal (Derech HaShem ח"ד פ"ח) says that the point of **the joy of Purim is the קבלת התורה - celebrating the re-acceptance of the Torah.**

Practically speaking, you could start by studying the above 2 passages, to gain a better understanding of the reason behind the joy of Purim and how to prepare for it.

You could then learn relevant Midrashim on the Megilla related to the  ונהפוך הוא  and the קבלת התורה .

Comment: if this is the case then isn't that implicit in the idea of learning about ANY holiday 30 days before it happens? And wouldn't it be equally appropriate for Kislev, and even moreso, for Nisan?

Answer (score -1):

In Av, when we are supposed to REDUCE Simcha, we are commanded to refrain from meat and wine. so...

Comment: Meat and wine are only prohibited by law at the last meal before Tisha Bav. Haircuts and bathing are only prohibited by law the week of Tisha Bav. What specifically is prohibited from Rosh Chodesh?

Comment: are you Sefardi? Ashkenazim have more restrictions.

Comment: Ashkenazim have some customs that they follow, but it's hard to learn from those late customs what Chazal meant to do in Adar, when they said "Mishenichnas Adar Marbim beSimcha". In fact, from the fact that they didn't prohibit meat and wine in Av is proof that that isn't what they meant for Adar.